# Sorting after using wc on files from a directory

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, terminal, wc

Specify a command / set of commands that displays the number of lines of code in the `.c` and `.h` files in the current directory, displaying each file in alphabetical order followed by`:` and the number of lines in the files, and finally the total of the lines of code. .
An example that might be displayed would be:

```
main.c: 202
util.c: 124
util.h: 43
TOTAL: 369
```

After many attempts, my final result of a one-liner command was :

```
wc -l *.c *.h | awk '{print $2 ": " $1}' | sed "$ s/total/TOTAL/g"
```

The problem is that i don't know how to `sort them alphabetically` without moving the `TOTAL` aswell (`considering we don't know how many files are in that folder`). I'm not sure if the command above is that efficient so if you have a better one you can include more variations of it.

Comment: `to sort them` - Would be great if you would post expected output matching the input showed. You want to sort it using file names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps easier would be to sort the input arguments to `wc` -- perhaps something like this:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 '(' -name '*.py' -o -name '*.md' ')' | sort | xargs -d'\n' wc -l | awk '{print $2": "$1}' | sed 's/^total:/TOTAL:/'
./__main__.py: 70
./README.md: 96
./SCREENS.md: 76
./setup.py: 2
./t.py: 10
TOTAL: 254
```

note that I use `xargs -d'\n'` to avoid filenames with spaces in them (if I were targetting GNU+ I would drop the `.` from `find .` and perhaps use `-print0 | sort -z | xargs -0` instead)

Comment: Only one problem left with this command :  how to remove the `./` from file names ? Also could you explain me how the `s/^total:/TOTAL:/` works without modifying file names ?

Comment: you could use more sed to do that: `sed 's|^\./||g'` for instance will remove the leading `./` -- as for "works without modifying filenames" -- it works unless the filename starts with `total:`

Comment: Managed to solve that one. Also another problem : it shows hidden files. How can I fix that ?

Comment: can of course use more sed or grep or whatever to filter files that start with a `.`

Answer (score 1):

You could save input into a variable, extract the last line, sort everything except the last line and then output the last line:

```
printf '%s\n' 'main.c: 202' 'util.c: 124' 'util.h: 43' 'TOTAL: 369' | {
    v=$(cat);
    total=$(tail -n1 <<<"$v");
    head -n-1 <<<"$v" | sort -r;
    printf "%s\n" "$total";
}
```

Comment: Need to do it shorter and in a one-liner. Also the printf won't work as i mentioned --considering we don't know how many files are in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

here's a meme-ier answer which uses `python3.8`+ (hey `awk` is turing complete why not use python?)

```
python3.8 -c 'import sys;s=0;[print(x+":",-s+(s:=s+len(list(open(x)))))for x in sorted(sys.argv[1:])];print("TOTAL:",s)' *.py *.cfg
__main__.py: 70
setup.cfg: 55
setup.py: 2
t.py: 10
TOTAL: 137
```

expanding it out, it abuses a few things:

- `len(list(open(x)))` - `open(x)` returns a file, `list` exhausts the iterator (by lines) and then the length of that is the number of lines
- `-s+(s:=s+...)` -- this is an assignment expression which has the side-effect of accumulating `s` but having the expression be the difference (`...`)
- `sorted(sys.argv)` satisfies the sorting part